# @Transactional on a public method called inside a Bean: HHH000437

Tags: spring, jpa, transactional

I have strange behavior with **@Transactional** annotation. The code works well with @Transactional on the **caller**:

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

private javax.persistence.EntityManager em;

@Transactional
public void caller(String login) {
    callee(login);
}

public void callee(String login) {
    user = new User(login);
    em.persist(user);
    userInfo = new UserInfo();
    userInfo.setUser(user);
    em.persist(userInfo);
}
```

But the following implementation returns an **error** on the second **em.persist** with @Transactional on the **callee**:

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

private javax.persistence.EntityManager em;

public void caller(String login) {
    callee(login);
}

@Transactional
public void callee(String login) {
    user = new User(login);
    em.persist(user);
    userInfo = new UserInfo();
    userInfo.setUser(user);
    em.persist(userInfo); // ERROR: org.hibernate.action.internal.UnresolvedEntityInsertActions : HHH000437: Attempting to save one or more entities that have a non-nullable association with an unsaved transient entity. The unsaved transient entity must be saved in an operation prior to saving these dependent entities. 
}
```

Error returned:

```
org.hibernate.action.internal.UnresolvedEntityInsertActions : HHH000437: Attempting to save one or more entities that have a non-nullable association with an unsaved transient entity. The unsaved transient entity must be saved in an operation prior to saving these dependent entities.    
Unsaved transient entity: ([package.entities.User#<null>])  
Dependent entities: ([[package.entities.UserInfo#<null>]])  
Non-nullable association(s): ([package.entities.UserInfo.user])
```

Does someone have an idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: Spring uses proxies to apply AOP, which basically means that only method calls INTO (external) the object retrieve AOP, internal method calls by pass the proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because Spring creates proxy beans around your classes, and only methods of a proxy are enhanced with annotated behavior. When you annotate a private method, it is called from within your class and can't be called through proxy, resulting in annotation being ignored.

@M. Deinum is right I think, corrected version of my answer. So, only the annotated method has the transaction support, but **only** if called through spring proxy. If you call it from the bean itself, as you do, it won't work.

In order for this to work, you would have to use something like this

```
context.getBean(MyBean.class).callee(login);
```

Comment: Sorry ithere was an error in my question: both method are public, there is no private

Comment: It's not so much whether the method is private (we can see it's public). Instead this would imply that this is a bean implementation class and the interface does not have the second `callee` method. In which case, Spring AOP can't proxy the method. Is that the case?

Comment: @Steve The second method was private in the original question. Anyway, your theory makes sense to me.

Comment: btw - It may be worth considering enabling AspectJ proxying. Just add `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>` if you're using XML config or `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` for Java config. That way, you get compile-time code weaving instead of dynamic proxies, which rely on the interface.

Comment: Thank you all! So to answer you, this bean has no interface, but maybe adding an interface to implement would solve the question. To be tested!

Comment: @Pleymor The comment from M. Deinum is correct, I've added an explanation in my answer.

Comment: @Predrag Maric You are totally right and your solution works fine, Thank you ! So just autowire the following:
`@Autowired private ApplicationContext context;`

and use 

`context.getBean(MyBean.class).callee(login);`